# Problem with apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libreoffice

I tried to install lynx to show someone how lynx works but when I ran `apt-get install lynx`, this is what happens.

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lynx is already the newest version (2.8.9dev8-4ubuntu1).
lynx set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:5.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-breeze : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-elementary : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-galaxy : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-oxygen : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So naturally i try both `sudo apt-get -f install`, here is what happens:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-sifr
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 345619 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.2-9782
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So now I'm stuck. I have no clue how to fix this problem.  Googling offers no help as everything everyone suggests fails to work.

People suggest running `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice* --purge` but again, no `apt-get` commands work because it is hung up on this crap error that tells me to fix it by doing the `-f install`.

If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know. I'd really hate to have to format and start over.

---

When I try to remove the spurious OpenOffice.org installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove -f 'openoffice.*'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-debian-menus' for glob 'openoffice.*'
[...snip...]
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:5.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-breeze : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-elementary : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-galaxy : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-oxygen : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice5.2-base : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-calc : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-dict-en : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-dict-es : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-dict-fr : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-draw : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-en-us : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-impress : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                          Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-math : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
 libreoffice5.2-writer : Depends: libreoffice5.2 (>= 5.2.4.2) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libreoffice5.2 (<= 5.2.4.2-2) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

<sup>([unabridged version](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23776525/))</sup>

Comment: sudo apt-get remove -f openoffice*
zsh: no matches found: openoffice*


I'm on Kubuntu 16.04 which Ive been told is nearly identical to Ubuntu except for the desktop environment.

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23776525/

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23779033/

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23779925/

Looks like nothing can successfully run because of these dependency problems

Comment: I appreciate the help David (and everyone else)

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23781544/

still no go =(

Comment: question. what is  the 's/^i //p'  in the sed command? My first thought was its some sort of regex pattern  so I looked at the output dpkg query vs piping it to sed, and noticed some items were missing, but the query doesnt make sense the way I was thinking .. anyways.. heres the result



http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23785041/

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23785907/

David Foerster just proved everyone that told me to format/start over clearly has something to learn from this AWESOME DUDE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH DAVID!!!!!!!! I think you've fixed it. If you lived in Los Angeles I'd buy you a drink!... and a steak... and donuts.. and pizza.. and bratwurst... and schnitzel!

Comment: The two pastie links are the same. I recapped the solution based on our interaction in an answer, added some crucial information to your question and will delete my now obsolete comments. I recommend you so the same with yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our interaction in the comments we identified an LibreOffice v5.2.* installation and left-overs of an OpenOffice.org installation in addition to the partial LibreOffice v5.1.* installation from Ubuntu's default package repositories. We could solve the issue by

1. removing (the remnants of) LibreOffice v5.2.* and OpenOffice.org manually:

   ```sh
   dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' openoffice\* libreoffice5.2\* libobasis5.2\* |
   sed -ne 's/^i //p' |
   xargs sudo dpkg --remove
   ```

   (Explanation as requested: the first field on each line of the `dpkg-query` output is the package status (as defined by the `-f` format option). `i` means "installed", so `sed -ne 's/^i //p'` will only print lines starting with `i` and also remove that part.)
2. and then fixing the remaining package management issues with Apt and providing a hint for the selection of a solution that involves the installation of `libreoffice-common` (from the default repositories):

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install -f libreoffice-common
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your invitation! I almost went on a road trip with friends through California incl. LA last spring (but we ended up doing one through Québec and New York – too bad is was freezing cold), though we might make another soon. So, I might take you up on that offer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your LibreOffice application data folder got messed up, the easy workaround is removing them:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/soffice
sudo rm -r /var/lib/libreoffice
```

If you want to continue using LibreOffice, it would be wise to remove OpenOffice, possibly that's the reason there are `openoffice-debian-menus` package:

```
sudo apt-get purge openoffice
sudo apt-get purge openoffice-debian-menus
```

Followed by installation of Latest LibreOffice:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-gnome
```

Source: [apt stuck with libreoffice errors](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=120527)

Comment: I dont have /usr/bin/soffice or /var/lib/libreoffice folders.
I do not wish to use either libreoffice or openoffice.
which openoffice returns openoffice not found (assuming its not installed)

running sudo apt-get purge openoffice returns the following:  http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23769311/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to use Openoffice and Libreoffice together... (?)
Apt cant configure libreoffice-common because it will overwrite
openoffice-debian-menus, which is installed too.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.2-9782
```

Try to remove openoffice (openoffice-debian-menus) and do the "install -f" again...

Greetings

Comment: I dont have openoffice =(  and apparently I dont have libreoffice either as it fails to install. I recently did a kubuntu-desktop install which I dont remember if it failed or not. I started it and came back to the pc days later. 

How would I remove openoffice? 

which openoffice  returns 
openoffice not found

Comment: @kate_h Here's a suggestion: Backup and do a fresh install of whatever Ubuntu flavor you like. What you have now is really messed up. Although it should be possible to fix it won't be easy and will take longer than the suggestion above -and- will certainly require an extensive troubleshooting that just isn't compatible with a Q&A format.

Comment: thanks celticwarrior this is what i was fearing because ive spent countless hours configuring this and that.. hours upon hours delving into dot files to get everything working how i like it.  and im not that experienced with having like portable dot files where i can easily just wipe out and start over and restore my custom configuration of everything. =(

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove libreoffice with dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -r 'libreoffice*'
```

You can also list the informations for libreoffice with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -l 'libreoffice*'
```

And i think you have already Lynx installed

```
lynx is already the newest version (2.8.9dev8-4ubuntu1).
lynx set to manually installed.
```

Comment: yea I cant remember the name of the app I was trying to install so I just used lynx to get my point across.  anyways..

ran both of your commands. pastebin below


http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23769519/

Comment: Yeah sry, this was in the documentation from dpkg from ubuntuusers. Try this one: sudo dpkg -P libreoffice

Comment: dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libreoffice which isn't installed

Comment: Hmm that will be difficult. Try this one sudo aptitude purge libreoffice* , if this dont work, then try this one: sudo aptitude purge libreoffice-common

Comment: i dont have aptitude.   should i try just apt ?   as in
sudo apt purge libreoffice*  
sudo apt purge libreoffice-common

Comment: Install aptitude with the following command: sudo apt-get intall aptitude , and pls go sure, that you really have no openoffice or libreoffice or something else. And also try sudo aptitude purge libreoffice-core . Here is an link to an topic where the same question was asked: [link]https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=55877

Comment: this is the exact problem.   apt-get is broken and i cant do anything until this problem is fixed.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23769668/

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23769670/

Comment: Sorry dont thought about that. Then you must try it with apt and i posted an link with an topic with the same question and problem

Comment: no worries, thanks for trying to help. That link doesnt help either. I tried installing debs manually and nothing seems to work. I'm not trying to get any office app working. i originally was trying to fix my plasma desktop that was corrupted. I was following a bunch of forums and trying many things. I think installing kubuntu-desktop is what screwed everything up.

Comment: I think its because you installed kubuntu-desktop and it has the package libreoffice in it. Use the following commands to remove the kubuntu-desktop installation: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23770241/

Comment: thanks ZeroFirst.. Only problem is I cant successfully run any apt-get commands as it's currently hung up on the libreoffice depends crap.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23773580/

Comment: Hm ok i think you broke the OS and the Packet dependencies the fastest way to fix this is to backup your data and reinstall, an workaround would take too long. But if you want to workaround this problem, then read some dpkg documentations, i think that must be the right way.

Answer (score -1):

You can run this command in terminal

`apt-get remove -f`

which you want to  remove

Thanks!

Comment: OP tried that without success. Also, OP doesn't want to remove anything directly – only if it helps solve packaging issues but for that you'd need to tell OP *which* packages to remove.